# How to create DF with exclude of just some fields from ready schema

Tags: pyspark, schema

I have a schema:

```
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("COUNTRY", StringType(), False),
        StructField("ID", StringType(), False),
        StructField("DATE", DateType(), False),
        ... x80
]
```

and I'd like to create a DF with only 30 of fields from such schema.
How to do it in an efficient way?

What I do, but it seems not eficient - I'm looking for more effective way. Is there such?

```
created_df_with_only_few_fields_from_the_schema = self.create_df(
                    [
                     {
                      "COUNTRY": "Germany",
                      ... x30
                    },schema["ID","DATE",... x30] --> all the fields that I'd like to extract
                     ]
```

Comment: What would be the criteria for selecting the fields?

Comment: Hardcoded. I know the fields that need to be chosen.

Comment: so by name. you want to pass a list as criteria, right?

Comment: Be careful not create yourself innumerable problems in the name of automation. If you know the names, it cheaper timewise to create a schema for the thirty fields.

Comment: You might be right. Then it's easier to edit them and fix some issues in the future. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

So you can just read the data with all the fields first, and then select the ones you need. *e.g.,*

```
selected_cols = ["col1", "col3", "col10", ... 30 fields]
selected_df = original_df[selected_cols]
```